# Large JSON file read, replace and write

Tags: python, json

What I am trying to do is load a JSON file (that has many objects), iterate through every object and replace dashes with something, in this case just the string "TEST" to see if it works.

```
get_file = open("ntp-2019-03-13T1600", "r")
json_data=""

for obj in get_file:
    json_data = json_data + json.dumps(obj).replace("-", "TEST")

get_file.close()

new_file = open("formatted_ntp/zzz", "w+")
new_file.write(json.loads(json_data))
new_file.close()
```

Running this code, I get this error:

```
>     JSONDecodeError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
>     <ipython-input-26-cf175a001140> in <module>()
>          30 
>          31 new_file = open("formatted_ntp/zzz", "w+")
>     ---> 32 new_file.write(json.loads(json_data))
>          33 new_file.close()
>          34 
>     
>     ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py in loads(s, encoding, cls, object_hook, parse_float, parse_int, parse_constant,
> object_pairs_hook, **kw)
>         352             parse_int is None and parse_float is None and
>         353             parse_constant is None and object_pairs_hook is None and not kw):
>     --> 354         return _default_decoder.decode(s)
>         355     if cls is None:
>         356         cls = JSONDecoder
>     
>     ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py in decode(self, s, _w)
>         340         end = _w(s, end).end()
>         341         if end != len(s):
>     --> 342             raise JSONDecodeError("Extra data", s, end)
>         343         return obj
>         344 
>     
>     JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 1 column 348 (char 347)
```

Now if I movie `json_data=""` inside the for loop, above `json_data = json_data + json.dumps(obj).replace("-", "TEST")` then the the newly formatted file is successfully written, but only the first object! This file has a around 100000 objects and I need the same operation done for all of them.

EDIT: objects are of the form:

```
{"af":4,"dst_name":"pool.ntp.org","from":"2.183.50.198","fw":4960,"group_id":2048605,"lts":-1,"msm_id":2048605,"msm_name":"Ntp","prb_id":33714,"proto":"UDP","result":[{"error":"name resolution failed: non-recoverable failure in name resolution (1)"}],"timestamp":1552493066,"ttr":5623.624915,"type":"ntp"}
{"af":4,"dst_addr":"193.0.0.229","dst_name":"193.0.0.229","from":"2.183.50.198","fw":4960,"group_id":2048606,"li":"no","lts":-1,"mode":"server","msm_id":2048606,"msm_name":"Ntp","poll":8,"prb_id":33714,"precision":0.0000038147,"proto":"UDP","ref-id":"GPS","ref-ts":3761485970.0366811752,"result":[{"x":"*"},{"final-ts":3761482699.4551954269,"offset":-3274.989631,"origin-ts":3761482694.3486270905,"receive-ts":3761485971.891418457,"rtt":5.106322,"transmit-ts":3761485971.8916659355},{"x":"*"}],"root-delay":0,"root-dispersion":0.00102234,"src_addr":"10.5.50.240","stratum":1,"timestamp":1552493894,"type":"ntp","version":4}
{"af":4,"dst_name":"pool.ntp.org","from":"2.183.50.198","fw":4960,"group_id":2048605,"lts":-1,"msm_id":2048605,"msm_name":"Ntp","prb_id":33714,"proto":"UDP","result":[{"error":"name resolution failed: non-recoverable failure in name resolution (1)"}],"timestamp":1552493962,"ttr":12032.946445,"type":"ntp"}
{"af":4,"dst_addr":"193.0.0.229","dst_name":"193.0.0.229","from":"2.183.50.198","fw":4960,"group_id":2048606,"lts":-1,"msm_id":2048606,"msm_name":"Ntp","prb_id":33714,"proto":"UDP","result":[{"x":"*"},{"x":"*"},{"x":"*"}],"src_addr":"10.5.50.240","timestamp":1552494794,"type":"ntp"}
{"af":4,"dst_name":"pool.ntp.org","from":"2.183.50.198","fw":4960,"group_id":2048605,"lts":-1,"msm_id":2048605,"msm_name":"Ntp","prb_id":33714,"proto":"UDP","result":[{"error":"name resolution failed: non-recoverable failure in name resolution (1)"}],"timestamp":1552494860,"ttr":954.17154,"type":"ntp"}
```

Comment: I think the data you are loading may be in json format, but also contain data in a different format. Hence the `JSONDecodeError: Extra  data` error. Check the source data.

Comment: to answer your second point, the reason why when you move `json_data=""` inside the for-loop only ends up writing one object is because every loop resets what the previous loop did since you are resetting `json_data` every time

Comment: edited the OP with some objects. Is that not JSON?

Comment: You should just write `json_data` to the file.

Comment: You have `json.loads` and `json.dumps` backwards. `loads` is converting a string to an object, `dumps` is for converting an object to a string.

Comment: If you just want to replace the string X with the string Y in a file, why dont you read the file into a string, call `replace` and save the new string to a file?

Comment: You almost certainly don't want to replace the `-` in the integer value `-1`, but we're left to make that assumption. It would be best to show exactly what you want your output to be, given the example input you've shown (or a different sample input if that would be more demonstrative).

Comment: as @Barmar pointed out, yes, I only want to change the ``-`` from attributes, not numeric values

Comment: nevermind I can just remove the - by replacing with "" , i dont care about the actual values. This is a big data project, I just needed huge amounts of data:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `json.loads` and `json.dumps` backwards. `json.loads` is for parsing a JSON string into an object, `json.dumps` is for converting an object to a JSON string.

But you don't need to do either, you can operate on the string you're reading from the file.

```
with open("ntp-2019-03-13T1600", "r") as get_file, open("formatted_ntp/zzz", "w") as new_file:
    for line in get_file:
        new_file.write(line.replace("-", "TEST"))
```

Note that this can create invalid JSON in the new file. If you have a negative number like `-1` in the original JSON, it will become `TEST1`.

If you want to avoid this problem, you need to parse each line with `json.loads()`. Then search through it recursively looking for all the values that are strings, and perform the replacement only on those values. Then use `json.dumps()` to convert that object back to JSON and write it to the file followed by newline.

Comment: Thank you. Yes that does pose a problem! I will work on that next.

Comment: Nevermind I can just replace with "" and get the ``-`` out of it